# $\int\sqrt{1-\tan x}~\mathrm{d}{x}.$ (Integral of a trigonometric function under square root)

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals, substitution, trigonometric-integrals

$\int\sqrt{1-\tan x}~\mathrm{d}{x}.$ is an integral which I am not able to solve. I have restricted my ideas on trigonometric substitution but cannot conclude to an answer...will really appreciate if someone could help me out..or suggest an alternative method for the same ..

Comment: $$\sqrt{1-\tan x}\mapsto \frac{\sqrt{1-x}}{1+x^2}\mapsto \frac{\sqrt{x}}{1+(1-x)^2}\mapsto \frac{x^2}{1+(1-x^2)^2}$$ and partial fraction decomposition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Substituting $u=\sqrt{1-\tan x}$ gives a pretty easy integral.

Comment: Okay sir...will try this out and update soon.thank you.